# How I can insert a 3rd nested list in a already existing list in python?

Tags: python

I have a list called `ilist` which looks like this:

```py
    ['TCS', 1968, ['Mumbai', 'Delhi', 'Kochi', 'Banglore', 'Pune'], 'Wipro', 1981, ['Pune', 'Banagalore', 'Pune']]
```

Now I want to insert some additional values in a form of list something like highlighted one below:

```py
    ['TCS', 1968, ['Mumbai', 'Delhi', 'Kochi', 'Banglore',**["ITPL","Whiteflied"]**, 'Pune'], 'Wipro', 1981, ['Pune', 'Banagalore', 'Pune']]
```

I thought to try the insert method, which I was able to use to insert 2nd nested loop like this:

```py
    ilist.insert(2,['Mumbai','Delhi','Kochi','Banglore','Pune'])
```

But as the insert method take only one argument, i.e the index where we want to insert the value. How we can give it like below:

```py
    ilist.insert(2,3,"ITPL","Vedhi","Electronic city")
```

this is giving error. Which I know will always come:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python Programs/Loops.py", line 41, in <module>
ilist.insert(2,3,"ITPL","Vedhi","Electronic city")
TypeError: insert() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given)
```

So what is the alternative method I can use to achieve the same? Apart from declaring a fresh list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to index the first list and then insert into the list at that index:

```
ilist[2].insert(3, ["ITPL","Vedhi","Electronic city"])
```